How was this equation for the stability of a finite difference model Wave Equation derived? Von Neumann analysis?
Wave Equation
In this paper, the following equation is given for a wave equation:



Stability Equation
They then go on to state the stability of such a wave equation in sample based solutions (in terms of space step $Δx = h$ here and time step $Δt = \frac{1}{f_s} = k$) is given by the following:



However no explanation is given for how this is solved. The only reference points to "S. Bilbao, Numerical Sound Synthesis, J. Wiley & Sons, 2009." which is a textbook I bought based on this in the hopes it would explain it. However, certainly no direct explanation is given and most of that book is over my head.

Partial Solution
Based on reply here, this can be derived (almost) through the following steps.
First $σ_0=0$ is assumed because this is a viscous drag force which will stabilize the wave equation, and it is at its least stable when $σ_0=0$, so this is how they likely decided to calculate it (to allow varying of $σ_0$).
Next, if you express their original wave equation as:
$$(∂_t^2 + κ^2∂_x^4 - c^2∂_x^2 - 2 σ_1 ∂_t ∂_x^2)u = 0$$
Then substitute the following:
$$∂_t u \simeq \frac{u(t+k) - u(t)}{k} \longrightarrow ∂_t \sim {2 \over k}$$
$$∂_x u \simeq \frac{u(x+h) - u(x)}{h} \longrightarrow ∂_x \sim {2 \over h}$$
The equation becomes a biquadratic like this:
$$h^2 = {(c^2 k^2 + 4 σ_1 k) ± \sqrt{(c^2 k^2 + 4 σ_1 k)^2 - 16 κ^2 k^2} \over 2}$$
Which replicates their solution except for the sign of the $κ$ term. I suspect then theirs has an error and this should in fact be negative but I am not sure.

Question
This leaves two issues:

Is there sign of the $κ$ term likely wrong?
More importantly, how do you get $∂_t \sim {2 \over k}$ and $∂_x\sim {2 \over h}$

Thanks for any help.

For a damped wave equation $$ \partial_t^2 = c^2 \ \partial_x^2 - \kappa^2 \partial_x^4 + \sigma \partial_t  + \dots  $$
the Fourier transform reads
$$ -\omega^2 \ \hat u = -c^2 \ k^2 \ \hat u  \ + \ \kappa ^2 \ k^4 \ \hat u \ - \ i \sigma \ \omega \  \hat u  \ + \ \dots   $$
The right hand side has to be an elliptic operator, that has an inverse.  Its real part must be negative in order to yield a wave equation, so the higher order x-derivatives must be limited somhow wrt to the leading k^2 term. Finally the damping must be negative for any k-mode.
Next step is to guarantee these conditions on a lattice approximation. that is, the acceleration term must be attractive to the mean by the mean of the second order differences $$\partial_t^2- \partial_x^2 =0 \to \ddot x_i = (x_{i+1}+x_{i-1}-2 x_i)$$  and the forth order differences  $$ \partial_x^4 \to (\ddot x_{i+1}+\ddot x_{i-1}-2 \ddot x_i)$$ should be small in ordeer not to destroy ellipticity discretized, meaning unique time forward solvability for a time step dt for a given x-configuation at time t.

Thank you for your reply, but this is still too advanced for my understanding. (1) What are $û$ and $ω$? (2) How did you get that $∂^2_t−∂^2_x=0$? (3) Can you show how this leads to the equation they provided for the time and space stability relationship (their equation 10)?

I have updated my question with a partial derivation for the equation. There are just two remaining I am wondering if you can explain or offer any solution for. Thanks again for your time.
